# Scroll View Size not match with the device screen in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

Ok, I tried the page with several buttons but all of them will not fit in one screen.  So, I create the scroll view and the view and then put all of buttons inside the view. The storyboard look fine. Other devices such as iPhone 5 and 5S look fine but when I tried 6 and 6 plus, the size of scroll view was incorrect.  I couldn't figure what went wrong.

[image: storyboard]

[image: tree1]

[image: tree2]

[image: iPhone 5s]

[image: iPhone 6]

Comment: Do you mean the width of the buttons are not correct in iPhone6/6plus? Please provide more details as to what you mean by "the size of scroll view was incorrect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify constraint for

1. scrollview with uncheck constraint to margin with all left right
   bottom and top is zero
2. Container view to super view set equel width constraint
3. container view to scrollview set horizontal center constraint.
4. Each UIBUtton set top/left/bottom with constant height not set bottom constraint.

[image: All BUttons constraint corresponding my screen]

[image: Container view and scrollview constraints]

[image: iPhone 6 output]

[image: iPhone 6Plus Output]

Comment: In yours constraint window red arrow indicates some of constraint have errors which required to adjust to get right output.

Comment: If you want to set container view height equel to device screen the you can modify constraint like Firstly remove bottom space constraint for last button and then set container view equel height with scroll view .. it will adjust view to full screen.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thank you so much!