# UIScrollView issue while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone

I have `UIScrollView` and `UITextFields` which both are done using size classes. The `UIScrollview` scrolls, but the problem is that when I scroll it scrolls horizontally as well as vertically.

However, I only require vertical scrolling.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwlIXXitbZCiN05EdmI0WF9UWFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In autolayout you have to insert sub items in scrollview through a container view in ScrollView. Then You have to set equel width constraint for container view with scrollview SuperView Width . Then It may be help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819782/scroll-view-size-not-match-with-the-device-screen-in-xcode/31832570#31832570 see this link to set autolayout for scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep width of UIScrollView less then or equal to its parent view width. Then it will stop scrolling vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the scroll view width as width of the device screen. It might be helpful.

```
   //Change the scroll view width with this
   UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width;
```

Comment: Yes I did it. I set the constraint equal width as view. Then ambiguity problem is cleared. But it scrolls  horizontally too.

Comment: Try setting the width equal to width of your Label/TextField.

Answer (score 1):

In the XIB, set the trailing space and leading space to the edges of screen as 0.

After that make sure that width of **Content Size** of your scroll view is equal to width of the screen.

It will work fine.